# ¿Cuál es la longitud máxima de una cadena (String) de Python?

Tags: python, string

Si es independiente del entorno, ¿cuál es el número máximo teórico de caracteres en una cadena de Python?

<sub>Traducido de: [What is the max length of a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string)

Autor original de la pregunta: [Citronic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178511/citronic)</sub>

Comment: Pensando un poco sobre el valor devuelto por el método `len()`, que devuelve la cantidad de caracteres de una cadena, como un valor entero, y siendo que en Python 3.x, no existe un límite sobre el tamaño de un número entero, excepto el límite físico de memoria de la que dispongas, sería justo decir que tampoco hay un límite para la cantidad de caracteres de una cadena en Python. Pero, no soy experto del lenguaje, y puedo equivocarme, alguien con más conocimientos podría darte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: ¿Candidato para [asociación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967)?

Comment: Más allá de la pregunta, muy buena por cierto, no es recomendable tener strings grandes en memoria, ya que de por si no es bueno tener mucha memoria ocupada al cohete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En **CPython**, que es la implementación python más común, existe el límite [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) como tamaño máximo que puede tener una estructura para ser referenciada. Es un límite impuesto por el lenguaje C y su aritmética de punteros y suele ser `2**63 - 1` (`2**31 - 1` si usas una plataforma de 32-bits). Éste es el límite de tamaño de listas, diccionarios y cadenas. Teóricamente podrías tener cadenas más largas, pero sus elementos no podrían ser referenciados.

Entrando en detalle, `sys.maxsize` se corresponde con el tipo `Py_ssize_t` que es el tipo que se usa para referenciar los elementos de una estructura en python. Se corresponde con el tipo `size_t` de C que, en el estándar C99, no tiene valor definido, tan sólo se dice que es un entero sin signo. Como en python se usa tanto valores positivos como negativos para los índices, `Py_ssize_t` es un entero con signo cuyo mayor valor positivo se corresponde con `2**63 - 1`.

Teóricamente, el mayor tamaño de una cadena que podemos *tratar* es de **9223372036854775807** caracteres. No hay ordenador con memoria suficiente para manejar cadenas de este tamaño.

Algo más de información en el [PEP-353](https://peps.python.org/pep-0353/).

Answer (score 0):

Con una instalación de Python de 64 bits y (digamos) 64 GB de memoria (RAM), una cadena de Python de alrededor de 63 GB debería ser bastante factible, pero no máximamente rápida. Si puede actualizar su memoria más allá de 64 GB, sus cadenas máximas factibles deberían ser proporcionalmente más largas. (No recomiendo confiar en la memoria virtual para extender eso mucho, o sus tiempos de ejecución se volverán simplemente ridículos ;-).

Con una instalación típica de Python de 32 bits, la memoria total que puede usar en su aplicación está limitada a 2 o 3 GB (según el sistema operativo y la configuración), por lo que las cadenas más largas que puede usar serán mucho más pequeñas que en instalaciones de 64 bit con grandes cantidades de RAM.

<sub>Traducido de: [What is the max length of a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string)

Autor original de la respuesta: [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

En Python, la longitud máxima de un string está determinada por la cantidad máxima de memoria disponible en tu sistema y la arquitectura de tu computadora. No hay una longitud máxima predefinida para los strings en Python.

En la práctica, puedes crear y manejar strings con longitudes muy grandes en Python sin encontrar problemas de límites específicos de longitud. Sin embargo, es importante considerar las limitaciones de memoria de tu sistema al trabajar con strings o cualquier otro tipo de datos.